PHP 8.3 NUSOAP SERVER CLIENT
Estoy realizando la migración de PHP 5.4 a PHP 8.3
Necesito una versión de NUSOAP para el PHP 8.3 ya que la que actualmente se tiene nusoap-0.9.5 no funciona y brinda estos errores

http://192.168.0.5/tmp/server.php?wsdl
This service does not provide WSDL
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function Consultaclaseplaca() on null in C:\paginas\esipeins\csp\csp-0033.srv.php:7378 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\paginas\esipeins\csp\csp-0033.srv.php on line 7378

Agradezco cualquier información que puedan brindarme
Bendiciones

No estoy seguro, pero parece que solo esta esto para la 8.2 -> https://github.com/f00b4r/nusoap

gracias, voy a reconfigurar todo para el PHP 8.2 y verificar ese NUSOAP

ya descargué todo para PHP 8.2 y ahora nada me funciona, voy de nuevo desde cero

Lo que preguntas se responde solo. Si estás usando una librería que estaba hecha para versiones anteriores a la 8 vas a tener muchos errores de ese tipo, considerando que muchas funciones y estructuras de control ya se hacen de manera diferente. Si no tienes opción, vas a tener que o hacerle un upgrade a la liberría o directamente parchar todos los errores de la actual y desactualizada librería para que funcione en versiones más nuevas de php.

Muchas gracias Don Fernando, tiene URL de donde puedo hacer el upgrade o la actualización de librerías?

Disculpe Don Fernando, tiene usted algún URL de donde pueda descargar NUSOAP completo incluyendo librerías?

https://github.com/contributte/nusoap da soporte hasta 8.2 pero asumo que no debe dar problemas en 8.3 , otra recomendacion seria migrar directamente todo a SoapClient y SoapServer ...

Buenas Don Francisco, ya descargué NUSOAP pero me da el siguiente mensaje:
Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property nusoap_proxy_1441883813::$faultactor is deprecated in C:\paginas\esipeins\nusoap4\src\nusoap.php on line 7784

ya lo corregí, era $this->$k = $v; y lo puse $k = $v;

vale puede ser que existan errores en estas libreria publicas, tomalo con pinsas ...

Como lo han dicho en los comentarios, la solución si o si es la migración a algo que le de soporte en la actualidad... ese algo debes decidirlo tú ... en el sitio no solemos recomendar librerías de tercero ni ayudar a buscarlas...
En el caso de implementar SoapClient y SoapServer sería así:
Soporte para: (PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8)
Servidor:
<?php
// server.php
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);

class MiServicio {
    public function Consultaclaseplaca($placa) {
        // Lógica del servicio
        return "Consulta realizada para la placa: $placa";
    }
}

$options = ['uri' => 'http://localhost/'];
$server = new SoapServer(null, $options);
$server->setClass('MiServicio');
$server->handle();

Documentacion: https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.soapserver.php
Cliente:
<?php
// client.php
$options = [
    'location' => 'http://localhost/server.php',
    'uri' => 'http://localhost/'
];

$client = new SoapClient(null, $options);
$result = $client->Consultaclaseplaca('ABC123');
echo $result;

Documentacion: https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php
En el caso de implementar nusoap de terceros, en los comentarios te han dado varias opciones.

un ejemplo de una implementación que he realizado:
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache", 0);
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);


class ControllerTFHKA
{

//... código ... de la clase


//... código ... de la clase implementacion de soap ...
public function GetFelTFHKA()
    {
        try {
            $ruta = URL_FEL2;
            $wsPa = new SoapClient($ruta, [
                'trace' => true,
                'keep_alive' => true,
                'connection_timeout' => 600,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,
            ]);
            $tokenEmpresa = HKA['USER'];
            $tokenPassword = HKA['PASS'];
            $parametros = [
                'tokenEmpresa' => $tokenEmpresa,
                'tokenPassword' => $tokenPassword,
                'documento' => $this->DocumentoElectronico,
            ];
            $result = $wsPa->__soapCall('Enviar', [$parametros]);
            $respWsPa = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
            
            return $respWsPa;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e);
        }
    }

//... código ... Fin de la clase implementacion de soap ...

//... código ... de la clase
}

En este ejemplo se implementa un objeto el cual sera enviado a un servicio SOAP de Facturacion electronica en conjunto con los token de authenticacion, hay varias constantes para no mostrar los secrects pero la implementacion en teoria deberia ser similar ...

añadí los dos ejemplos que usted me da, pero recibo el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "SoapClient" not found in C:\paginas\esipeins\tmp\client4.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\paginas\esipeins\tmp\client4.php on line 8

le puse NUSOAP y ahora me da el siguiente mensaje: Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\paginas\esipeins\nusoap4\src\nusoap.php on line 7559

esos son errores de implementacion ... no de código ...  y como no veo la implementacion que haces, es un poco difícil adivinar que terminaste haciendo...
